# How to make an AJAX request on page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to call `GetAllProperties()` function during page loading instead of calling the `GetAllProperties()` function after page is fully loaded. My code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {   
        GetAllProperties();    
    });
    function GetAllProperties() {    
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: '/Home/GetAllProperties',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.list.length > 0) {
                    console.log(response.list)
                    var $data = $('<table id="mytable"  class="table  table-striped"> </table>');
                    var header = "<thead><tr><th>Property Name</th><th>Edit</th></tr></thead>";
                    $data.append(header);
                    $.each(response.list, function (i, row) {
                        var $row = $('<tr/>');
                        $row.append($('<td/>').html(row.PropertyName));
                        $hidden = $(' <input type="hidden" name="hid" value= "' + row.PropertyId + '">');
                        $row.append($hidden);
                        $editButton = $("<button class='editbtn' id='mybtn'>Edit</button>");    
                        $row.append($editButton);
                        $deleteButton = $("<button class='deletebtn' id='delbtn'>Delete</button>");    
                        $row.append($deleteButton);
                        $data.append($row);
                    });        
                    $("#MyDiv").empty();
                    $("#MyDiv").append($data);
                }
                else {

                }
            },
            error: function (r) {
                alert('Error! Please try again.' + r.responseText);
                console.log(r);    
            }
        });    
    }    
</script>
```

I really need your help because i am new in jQuery

Thank you

Comment: have you tried debugging? like looking into the console of your browser? I'm not entirely sure, but I think a function should be defined before it is used...

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
        GetAllProperties();    
});
```

with just calling `GetAllProperties()`. you don't need DOM for ajax calls

Then replace

```
$("#MyDiv").empty();
$("#MyDiv").append($data);
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $("#MyDiv").empty();
    $("#MyDiv").append($data);
});
```

Operate with DOM when it's ready. Other actions you can do without DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to call function:
$(window).on('load', function() {GetAllProperties();});

Comment: Thank you for your help ,I tried this but still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the function while the page is loading you have to remove the

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
        GetAllProperties();    
    });
```

just call the function

```
GetAllProperties();
```

Comment: Thank you . i tried that and still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You want to start the function **during** loading and not afterwards? Then place the call `GetAllProperties();` as most early as possible. Best place would be in `<head>`.

But keep in mind, you need to place it **after** the inclusion of the `GetAllProperties` function itself. And the function has to be declared in the same file.

Otherwise the execution is delayed by loading the script file, or it is delayed by the loading DOM, when you place it at the bottom of your page.

Comment: Thank you so much for your lovely help.. I am very new to Jquery ..so can you please write a code to show me how to implement it? thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call javascript function while page load than you should try following function :

```
window.onload = function() {
  GetAllProperties();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. I solved by calling the function inside the `<body>` tag in html

```
<body onload="GetAllProperties()">
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Call your method just after including jquery:

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
      function GetAllProperties() {    
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: '/Home/GetAllProperties',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.list.length > 0) {
                console.log(response.list)
                var $data = $('<table id="mytable"  class="table  table-striped"> </table>');
                var header = "<thead><tr><th>Property Name</th><th>Edit</th></tr></thead>";
                $data.append(header);
                $.each(response.list, function (i, row) {
                    var $row = $('<tr/>');
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(row.PropertyName));
                    $hidden = $(' <input type="hidden" name="hid" value= "' + row.PropertyId + '">');
                    $row.append($hidden);
                    $editButton = $("<button class='editbtn' id='mybtn'>Edit</button>");    
                    $row.append($editButton);
                    $deleteButton = $("<button class='deletebtn' id='delbtn'>Delete</button>");    
                    $row.append($deleteButton);
                    $data.append($row);
                });        
                $("#MyDiv").empty();
                $("#MyDiv").append($data);
            }
            else {

            }
        },
        error: function (r) {
            alert('Error! Please try again.' + r.responseText);
            console.log(r);    
        }
    });    
}    
  GetAllProperties();    
<script>
```